# Best approach to turn a php array in a json object (not in a json single file)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Here's something I'm struggling today that I think it is time to share with other people who could have the same problem:

The goal is to obtain a JSON object that I can manipulate:

My php file:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$string = file_get_contents('https://myurl/photos.json');
$json_a = json_encode($string);
echo($json_a);
```

And my js file:

```
const themeFolder = object_name.templateUrl;
const urlPics = themeFolder + '/pics.php';

    const getPictures = () => {
        let content = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: urlPics, 
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);

            }
        });
    }
    getPictures();
}
```

I had this approach but there are several others to obtain a PHP array for example.

My problem is that I'm not able to parse the js file because I can only obtain a single JSON file which looks like something like that:

```
"{
\"photos\":[{
\"image\":\"url\/pic.jpg\",\"name\":\"Pic\",\"author\":\"Pic",\"link\":\"https:\\\/\\\/pic.com\\\/photos\\\/zBvVuRJ71vU\"
}
}]
}"
```

Even if I force to output a json file object with for example JSON_FORCE_OBJECT as a second parameter the file won't change at all.

My goal is to obtain a JSON object that I can easily parse with javascript, in this case, jQuery.

Any hint?

Comment: If the file is *already* JSON, there's no need to call `json_encode()` again.

Comment: Good catch, and I guess that I've just found a solution. I had to add to the ajax call dataType: "JSON", am I correct?

Comment: Well I'd simply leave out the `json_encode()` call and `echo($string)`.

Comment: Your approach might work because then jQuery will decode the (unnecessary) JSON your PHP code explicitly adds, and then your subsequent `JSON.parse()` will parse the actual JSON.

Comment: If I do in that way and then I tried to console.log the result.photos I will obtain an undefined value, but if I use dataType:"JSON" it will work

Comment: If you will post the solution, I will grade your answer, thank you so much for the hint